# Programmatically adding a new tax class into "Additional tax classes" in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to programmatically add a new tax class in WooCommerce from my custom plugin. I want to achieve the same functionality as adding a new tax rate class from "Additional tax classes" under "WooCommerce -> Settings -> Tax" but programmatically. A new section next to the default ones "Tax options | Standard rates | Reduced rate rates | Zero rate rates" must appear with my new class and the functionality must be the same as Standart rates, Reduced rate rates etc... A table where I can add different rates for different countries. I tried achieving this through WC_Tax class but without success:

```
function wm_add_additional_rate_tax_classes() {
    $silver_rates = WC_Tax::create_tax_class('Silver Metal', 'silver-metal-tax-rates');
    $platinum_rates = WC_Tax::create_tax_class('Platinum Metal', 'platinum-metal-tax-rates');
    $palladium_rates = WC_Tax::create_tax_class('Palladium Metal', 'palladium-metal-tax-rates');
}
add_action( 'init', 'wm_add_additional_rate_tax_classes' );
```

It's adding new tax rate classes and they appear next to "Tax options | Standard rates | Reduced rate rates | Zero rate rates" but when I click on any of them there is no interface for adding tax rates for different countires. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe add tax rates for countries programmatically as well?

Comment: @protob But the tax rates aren't pre-defined. They must be added from the administrator. That's why I need the interface that the other classes have.

Comment: @protob Any ideas? I'm really stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work as expected, maybe the bug is related to cache or something? Try this:

```
WC_Cache_Helper::invalidate_cache_group('taxes');
```

I don't know the reason of your problem. This code shows tax class with UI in dashboard, when pasted directly to functions.php:

```
function add_additional_rate_tax_classes()
{
    $tax_class_name = 'sample-tax-class';
    $tax_class_slug = 'sample-tax-class';
    $tax_class = WC_Tax::create_tax_class($tax_class_name, $tax_class_slug);
}

add_action('init', 'add_additional_rate_tax_classes');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't help. Any other idea?

Comment: I edited my answer but i have no idea, why it didn't work for you

Comment: So you say you tested it and it works for you?

Comment: Yeah, but only the code i pasted in answer i can add many tax classes and they show in UI. Your code is basically the same but it results in blank UI in dashboard for me. It's strange. Maybe it's something related class names then?

Comment: You're so right dude! It's because of the slugs. There was some conflict. Okay, very nice. What hook should I use for the creation of these tax classes? Init is not the proper one I guess. Maybe on plugin activation?

Comment: Great! One of those bugs when you waste a lot of time to find explanation of a simple thing. For hook, it depends, but yes you can use activation hook in this case. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/